# What is the context which the phrase "blow over" has been used in here?

Tags: phrase-usage

I read a sentence in a chapter named "Poet and Pancakes" which was:

> An extremely talented actress, who was also extremely temperamental, once blew over on the sets.

Most of the dictionaries define this phrase as - (of a situation) to calm down or to pass with little effect. But that doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: In NCERT textbook for class 12th named Flamingo,the quote from original poster is printed.

Comment: Reading that phrase as written (and as a native english speaker), I'd have taken it literally and assumed she got caught off-guard by some kind of wind generator prop that made her fall over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your quote is incorrect. [The quote](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LCCaCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&lpg=PT42&dq=An%20extremely%20talented%20actress,%20who%20was%20also%20extremely%20temperamental,%20once%20blew%20over%20on%20the%20sets.&source=bl&ots=kG5uvSXHQH&sig=ACfU3U1TPc3tyWuFTxG2LVKrnry5Rnuk4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwifqOL8ldThAhW1oXEKHaUXC40Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=An%20extremely%20talented%20actress%2C%20who%20was%20also%20extremely%20temperamental%2C%20once%20blew%20over%20on%20the%20sets.&f=false), from "Fourteen Years with Boss" actually reads:

> An extremely talented actress, who was also extremely temperamental, once blew **up** on the sets.

"Blow up" in this context means to have an angry outburst, which would seem to fit with the character of the "temperamental" actress.